# OpenSplice V6.3 fails on Network

Tags: opensplice

although i have been using OpenSplice V5 for connecting my platform running on different nodes, now i upgraded OPensplice to V6.3 but i am getting failures on my platform as if no connection.

what i did is that i tried connecting the helloWorld windows version (one 32 bit and another 64 bit) together on the default hello world example but with no success.

do anyone can help solving this issue and advise what parameters must be fine tuned on the ospl.xml file for using network connectivity using unicast?

thx,

Answer (score 1):

What I've seen before is that sometimes people use machines that have multiple interface-cards connected, in which case you have to explicitly configure the interface to use in the DDSI configuration (rather than the 'AUTO' default).

Furthermore, if you want to enforce unicast, you have to configure your unicast-peers in the DDSI discovery section of the config-file.

Note that DDSI also automatically switches between unicast and multicast depending on the number of discovered endpoints (i.e. it will use unicast in case only 1 endpoint is discovereed)